# HtmlRenderer C# not showing table border in Rendered Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-rendering

In my C# code I am rendering a JPEG image of a HTML page using a string variable (which holds my html code). There's a table in that html code whose borders are not being rendered in JPEG image.
I am using the following code to generate image :-

```
        string sHtml = m_Html; //m_Html contains the html code            
        Image img = HtmlRender.RenderToImage(sHtml);
```

Comment: Did you try to set properties of Image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thorough searching, I understood that HtmlRenderer renders the string which we pass (as a parameter) into a HTML page and then takes a snapshot. Now, the rendering engine which HtmlRenderer uses is not very sophisticated, it does not support latest/complex CSS queries.So if you are facing this issue, use simple HTML/CSS.

If still you are not able to solve the issue, use a different library 'NReco'. NReco is open source if you just use it, licensed if you want to modify it. NReco is better than HTML Renderer.